# My motorbike handle gets a hit when I hit a bump or pothole

Tags: motorcycle, suspension, gears, bajaj, india

My 2 month old bike is a 200CC Bajaj Pulsar (made in india) with only 2000kms on the odometer.
I have ridden it carefully. I touched 100km/h accidentally on a drag race with my friend, just one time, but mostly ride between 50-70km/h. I recently completed a +500km trip over bad terrain.

**Problems**

- The handle get a hit like there is no suspension every time I hit a pothole or a bump
- Gearbox is so annoying. 1st and 2nd gears are so noisy and most of the time the N will hit on gear change from 1st to 2nd

I didn't expect much quality or reliability. But, I'm not expecting these problems so soon.

Can you tell me what could cause these?

Comment: Can you clarify this please, "Gearbox is so annoying. 1st and 2nd gears are so noisy and most of the time the N will hit on gear change from 1st to 2nd"

Comment: Gearbox is annoying, its like hitting a drum every time you shift. And my gear pattern is 1N23456, so when i shift from 1st to 2nd it will be N that is set.

Comment: Just tighten the clutch dude mate.. will work properly. You get that (crackling)sound when the clutch is not pulled enough while the gear shift change.

Comment: @Anarach I got it bro. its the reply for first comment, who asked for it.

Comment: @BigByte - This is two separate questions.  You should remove the clutch bit and create a single question for that.

Comment: The con set or steering head bearing of my bike was loose and damaged. Got it replaced and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am supposing its a Bajaj Pulsar 200NS.

- problem 1: Your front Fork Oil Seal is broken(a good way to check is to notice any oil leaks near your forks) , This will cause issue with the suspension travel thus the issue.Secondly since you mentioned you did travel over bad terrain there is a slight chance of your fork bending, this will also cause suspension travel issue. Go to Ebay and get "sealmate" for your suspension oil leak issue or take it to the service station as for the fork bends , there is nothing you can do , Take it to the service station.
- Problem 2 The gearbox on bajaj vehicles are horrible that said, tighten your clutch , its common for bike to hit neutral if clutch is lose tightening the clutch should fix your gearbox problems.

Tips : DO not do clutch-less  down shifts on those bikes. I think that bike has around 24bhp why are you riding at such slow speeds? its not like if you ride slow your bike will last longer! It actually will sit still if you suddenly decide to open the throttle.Show the baby some love. Peace.

Comment: Thanks Anarach, but i didn't find any oil leaks near forks. what does it look like? does the oil comes out a lot?

Comment: Depends on the fork size, Not too much but definitely noticeable, Problem is that if you don't notice it for a month or two it will dry out and will not look like a leak any more so unless you check immediately there is no way to find out . Take it to a mechanic and let him have a look.

Comment: Ok, its just 2 months old, is that would be a fork bending by any chance?

Comment: Fork bending can happen any time, even while taking the bike to home from showroom.

Comment: @Anarach - How can you just make a claim like, "your front fork seal is broken"  The OP in NO WAY indicated that there is ANY OIL leaks in the suspension.  I've noticed you like to make 'IS' statements and proclaim the answer without having all of the information.  I think that's irresponsible.  I've read all the information and have seen the OP state that there is no oil leaks.  Please stop proclaiming and start using words like 'possibility' or 'possibly'.  It's irresponsible not to.

Comment: @DucatiKiller , I live in the same country as the OP and I know the conditions here , its a very different world than yours, I know how the parts are made , Have you seen Oil dry up? here in my country the Oil Dries UP its that hot and dusty. The Oil dries UP and sticks to the dust and falls off the bike like crumbs You will not notice a thing.  But I will take your suggestion to use words like 'possibility' or 'possibly'.Thank you.

Comment: Problems fixed : handle fork set and clutch tightened.

Comment: @K3yb0ard15T Good for you..

Answer (score 3):

## Possible Issues

1. Low probability - The oil in the forks is too high of a weight.  'Thicker' higher weight oil would make the forks seem very stiff.  As your motorcycle is relatively new and more than likely came with forks assembled from the factory, this is probably not the case.
2. Compression Dampening is too high - If you have a setting at the top of the forks where you can change the compression dampening to a lower setting, this may resolve your issue.  Having compression dampening set too high can cause the symptoms your describe.  Compression dampening is variable on most motorcycles and I am unsure if your model has this feature.
3. Riding Style - If you are using your breaks when your wheel goes into a pothole then you are riding your motorcycle improperly and will experience the symptoms you are describing related to the suspension.

## Howto Ride a Motorcycle on Rough Terrain

- Stand on the footpegs, protect your spine by standing on the footpegs or lifting your ass off the seat a bit using your legs.
- Unweight the front end - If your going over holes, stand up on the footpegs and stay off the brakes as you travel over the hole.  Do your best to avoid the hole, of course, but if you cannot make sure you are NOT BRAKING as you travel over the pothole.
- Apply gas - As you pass over large bumps or holes applying the gas in a lower gear to lift the front end a bit will reduce the chances of getting a 'bang' on your handlebars or front end.  Y
- Watch motorcross riders - get on youtube and watch how to ride on dirt. In many cases you will give gas to go over bumps
- Here is the key, you don't want all of your weight transfered to the front of the motorcycle when you hit bumps and holes.  You want the weight transferred as much to the rear wheel as you possible can.  USE YOUR THROTTLE!  UNWEIGHT THE FORKS.

IMO this is riding technique issue and not a mechanical one.

Best of luck to you!

Comment: Dude we need to talk in chat, rough terrain in India is totally not what you are expecting, Standing on the foot-pegs will  break them , since one of my friends broke his by doing so and got hurt pretty bad, Come on chat and we can probably discuss.

Comment: "No This bike does not have adjustable front shocks"

Comment: I"m traveling right now and will be in and out of communication.  What are the hours in GMT that you are usually interacting with the world?

Comment: Not even a point for that writeup.  Your culture is a tough crowd   :)

Comment: now would be a good time :-)

Comment: Midnight in Miami, Florida.  Traveled ALL day.  Need to get some sleep.  Happy to connect tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23979/discussion-between-ducatikiller-and-anarach).